# Why does this comparison return not equal?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Can't seem to get this to evaluate to true

```
is_equal () {
  in="$1"
  if [[ "$in" == "385" ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
a= is_equal 385
if [[ "$a" ]]; then
  echo "equal"
else
  echo "NOT equal"
fi

$ ./equal_nums.sh 
NOT equal
$
```

Comment: Try `a=$(is_equal 385)` But as for me better use `if is_equal 365 ; then ...`

Comment: Spaces! Why all the spaces? Also `$( is_equal ..)`.

Comment: `==`is a string or pattern comparison; `-eq` is for integers...

Comment: The function can be simplified also. It is useless operate `if test ... return ...` so the function can be `is_equal() { [[ "$1" -eq "385" ]] }`

Comment: @Costas I tried both your good suggestions but I still get NOT equal.

Comment: New version at http://jsfiddle.net/hraoc450/2

Comment: `[[ $a ]]` is equal `[[ -n $a ]]` and test if variable `$a` is not empty. Is that what do you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function has an exit status but no output. Your variable `$a` will always be empty, so the `[[ $a ]]` test will always be "false"

You truly want this:

```
if is_equal 42; then ...
```

But what you think you want is this

```
is_equal 42                # don't capture the output
a=$?                       # but do grab the exit status
if [[ $a -eq 0 ]]; then ...
```